# Can I use WAF to check if a request is coming from within a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-waf

I have a VPC and I want to use WAF on a cloudfront distribution to ensure that my request is coming from within the VPC. How can I do this?

Comment: Amazon CloudFront is _outside_ of VPCs. It would not make sense to send requests from a VPC to CloudFront, only to return to the VPC. Can you explain more about your _actual_ goal (that is, _what_ you want to achieve, rather than _how_)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm looking to make it so that only when connected to a VPN can I access my Cloudfront distribution. I see that you can add an IP set, but i don't know how to get the IP to add there. Is it my VPN private ip?

Comment: What would be the benefit of accessing CloudFront via a VPN connection? All traffic would come from a single location, which removes all benefits that Amazon CloudFront offers as a global CDN.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Lol--did not think about that. Can I add WAF rules directly to an S3 bucket? How could I make it so that my S3 bucket only allows traffic from my VPN's IP?

Comment: You can create a Bucket Policy with an `Allow` rule that permits access from a specific IP address. See: [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) **Tip:** It helps to provide information about _WHY_ you are doing something in a Question to achieve the most beneficial solution.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i see, but what would this ip be? Would it be the private ip of my vpn? thanks--super helpful and will do in the future.

Comment: It would be the IP address that traffic from your VPN 'appears' to be coming from. You can see it if you access https://whatismyipaddress.com/ via the VPN.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I gave that a shot but the IP doesn't seem to change when I turn on or off the VPN. I'm using an OpenVPN instance. Any reason why that might be? Thanks again!

Comment: That suggests that you are using "split tunnelling", where traffic destined for the target network goes via the VPN, but traffic to the Internet does _not_ go via your VPN connection. So, the request is not coming from the VPC.

Comment: `IP doesn't seem to change` you need to request the address from the VPC, not your workstation.   If you want to access the CDN from the workstation through the VPN in VPC, you have to change the routing for the dns